# How do I make a pivot table just for x and y data (for use in a scatter plot)?

Tags: excel, graph, pivot-table

I've been looking for a way to create a dynamic graph that I can filter by whatever month I want using the pivot table's filter feature. The x-values for my data set are time.

I know that I could just create a graph for all my data and then use Excel's auto filter feature for my x and y data (filtering x to limit the months displayed on the graph), but I have too many values, so the auto filter doesn't display all the months of the year, so there goes that idea.

Here's what I want my pivot table to display:

- A column listing all my x-values (time)
- A column listing all my y-values
- A filter for my x-values (time)

So yeah, basically the same thing as my input except I can filter it and it'll dynamically update a scatter plot I make.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have too many values?  Are you using more data than your pivot table is representing?

Comment: I don't have too many values for the pivot table (I don't think anyway). I have too many values to use Excel's auto filter and to have the auto filter display all values (or in this case just the months because it condenses time data into more manageable bits, but it's limited to 10,000 values). Anyway, auto filter is a different feature than the pivot table. Right now, I don't have a pivot table because I can't get it to display what I want. Basically, I want my pivot table to look identical to my input data.

Comment: If you have that much data then you're looking at way more than Excel is really optimal for.  A filter is really only optimal for a few dozen values, tops.  If you constrain your data set then you can achieve what you want.  Is it fair to assume that you are keeping all your data in Excel?  Not in a database?

Comment: I could, but the point is that I want to learn how to use pivot tables to display the same thing as my input, so I can just use a dynamic chart with the pivot table and don't have to manually input the months.

Comment: Excel didn't tell me it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel do you have?  I haven't tried it with the volume of data you seemingly have, but in 2013 or later, if you format your data as a Table (Home > Format as Table), you can add Slicers and Timelines (Under the Design menu when a cell within the table is selected).  This gives you a user friendly pane that lets you select a date range.  Not sure if you will run into the same issue with having too many date values, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. But is there a way to make a pivot table that looks the exact same as your input data (a column of x values and a column of y values)? That was never answered. I'm using Excel 2016

Comment: MechE - you probably need to upload an image or provide a link to an image showing what you mean. I think what you're talking about can be done using the Grouping feature of PivotTables, but it's hard to know without us having a firm idea of what your data looks like, and how you want it to display when done.